# SELECTED = SELECTED & Chain SELECTS PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have a Chain SELECT which is working great, but I want to be able to push data from a search records form on to this form which includes a Chain SELECT, how is it possible for me to use SELECTED = SELECTED within this code?

my select.class.php

```
<?php
class SelectList {
    public function ShowMake($searchboilermake) {
        include "./core/cnn.php";
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM blr_boilermake";
        $res = mysql_query($sql);
        $boilermake = '<option value=""></option>';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
            $boilermake .= '<option value="' . $row['BoilerID'] . '"';
            $boilermake .= ($row['BoilerID']==$searchboilermake) ? " selected='selected' " : "";
            $boilermake .= '>' . $row['BoilerMake'] . '</option>';
        }
        return $boilermake;
    }

    public function ShowModel() {
        include "../core/cnn.php";
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM blr_boilermodel WHERE BoilerModel IS NOT NULL AND BoilerID = $_POST[id]";
        $res = mysql_query($sql);
        $boilermodel = '<option value="0"></option>';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
            $boilermodel .= '<option value="' . $row['ModelID'] . '">' . $row['BoilerModel'] . '</option>';
        }
        return $boilermodel;
    }
}
$opt = new SelectList();
?>
```

from my form on my page I use this to pull in the select.class.php for the boilermake field

```
<label>Manufacturer</label>
<select class="select2_category form-control" data-placeholder="Choose a Category" tabindex="1" id="boilermanufacturer" name="boilermanufacturer">
<?php echo $opt->ShowMake($_REQUEST['boilermanufacturer']); ?>
</select>
```

and this for my boilermodel field

```
<label>Model</label>
<select class="select2_category form-control" data-placeholder="Choose a Category" tabindex="1" id="boilermodel" name="boilermodel">
 <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Within other SELECTS that are much more straight forward and standard SELECT I use this below, but how can I adapt this below to my Chain SELECT?

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Fuel Type</label>
<?php $fueltype = db::getInstance()->query('SELECT * FROM lkup_fueltype');
if(!$fueltype->count()) { 
    echo 'Problem'; 
} else { ?> 
<select class="select2_category form-control" data-placeholder="Choose a Category" tabindex="1" id="propertyfueltype" name="propertyfueltype">
<?php foreach ($fueltype->results() as $fueltype) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $fueltype->ID; ?>"<?php echo $fueltype->ID == $searchboilerfueltype ? "selected" : ""; ?>><?php echo $fueltype->PropertyFuelType; ?></option> <?php } } ?>
</select>
```

I tried to use this, but it didn't select the SELECTED row when I ran the code

```
$boilermake .= '<option value="' . $row['BoilerID'] . '" "' . $row['BoilerID'] . '" == $searchboilermake ? "selected" : "">' . $row['BoilerMake'] . '</option>';
```

What should I have done/or what can I do to get this to work?

Comment: I strongly advice you to read about [Deprecation of mysql_* extensions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) and [SQL Injections](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Why do you get part of your data from a `db` class and the other class manually?

Comment: The reason that I'm using both PDO & mysql_ is that the chain selects were one of the first things developed on the site before changing everything to PDO, as this currently works great with no issues and the attempts I've had with chain selects and PDO havent worked, so for the time being this is how it will stay.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you tried to use a boolean/ternary expression inside a string. That obviously will not evaluate in a string like that.

```
$boilermake .= '<option value="' . $row['BoilerID'] . '"';
$boilermake .= ($row['BoilerID']==$searchboilermake) ? " selected='selected' " : "";
$boilermake .= '>' . $row['BoilerMake'] . '</option>';
```

Edit: You need to fix the function `ShowMake` to pass in `$searchboilermake` as a parameter.

Definition of function:

```
public function ShowMake($searchboilermake) {
```

Call to function:

```
<?php echo $opt->ShowMake($_REQUEST['boilermanufacturer']); ?>
```

Comment: I tried this and still nothing shows when the page is loaded from the search page, I've echo'd the $searchboilermake on to the page so I know this returns a value

Comment: Using your code above still doesn't show $searchboilermake as the SELECTED when the form loads, why would this be? My edit above shows how now what you gave yesterday fits with my other code

Comment: Thanks, I added those edits into my code and still when I run the form, the SELECT for boilermake returns an empty SELECT, I know there is a value for the SELECT as I echo it out afterwards to make sure it returns the boilerID

Comment: Double check your db field name for the display part of the option. `$row['BoilerMake']` Is it really called BoilerMake? If that field doesn't exist, you'll just get empty string.

Comment: The field `$row['BoilerMake']` is right as when I select a boiler make from the SELECT then it will show, it's the $searchboilermake that isn't populating within the SELECT, yet if I echo that out seperately away from the SELECT it returns the boilerID